# Saving and Reading Images in Oracle with classic asp

Tags: oracle, file-upload, asp-classic, binary, clob

i am utilizing aspSmartUpload to upload an image into an Oracle BLOB field, see below:

```
Set mySmartUpload = Server.CreateObject("aspSmartUpload.SmartUpload")

    '*** Upload Files ***'
        mySmartUpload.Upload
        set file = mySmartUpload.Files("file1")
        Set MyConn  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
        Call OpenConnect(MyConn)
          sql = "SELECT attach_data, title, idx, attach_type_id FROM c_attachment"
          Set Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
          Set rs.ActiveConnection = MyConn
          rs.Source = sql
          rs.CursorLocation = 3
          rs.CursorType = 0
          rs.LockType = 3
          rs.Open sql

If not file.IsMissing Then 'Check for missing file
            'Add the current file in database
            Rs.AddNew
            file.FileToField Rs.Fields("attach_data")
            Rs("title") = "title test"
            rs("idx") = "134774"
            rs("attach_type_id") = 1
            Rs.Update
             rs.Close
            set rs = nothing
        End If
```

when i check the db table. attach_data is populated. now. when i try to read the image back, i keep getting "Response object: 007~ASP 0106~Type Mismatch~An unhandled data type was encountered." error on the BinaryWrite. please help!

```
Set MyConn  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
        Call OpenConnect(MyConn)
            SQLQuery = "select attach_data,title from c_attachment where attach_id = 109"
            Set RSList = MyConn.Execute(SQLQuery)
            If RSList.EOF Then
               blnImgExists = False
            Else
                        FileData = RSList("attach_data")
               blnImgExists = true
            End If
          if blnImgExists Then


   Response.Clear 
   Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
   Response.AddHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=image.jpg"
   Response.BinaryWrite RSList("attach_data")
   else
   response.write "count not open"
   end if
```

Comment: Just to clarify, images would be stored as BLOB not CLOB. Is the column a BLOB?

Comment: wow. i can't believe i did that. thanks! i will make it as answer, if you answer my question :)

Comment: @REW just poking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images should be stored as BLOB data (Binary Large Object) in Oracle, not CLOB (Character Large Object).